# views filter: broken filter - but what's broken about it?

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to build a views filter and after a lot of digging into the views-workflow, I think I might have understood the basics. I used a lot of resources [1](http://www.examiner.com/open-source-in-national/drupal-how-to-create-views-2-filters-for-your-new-module) [2](http://www.comm-press.de/blog/eigene-filter-f-r-das-drupal-views-modul) [3](http://zugec.com/drupal/creating-custom-filters-in-views-2) [4](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-filters-views) and of course [doc.logrus.com](http://views.doc.logrus.com/), but now Views tells me that my handler is broken.

If there is anybody outhere that can help me get my filter-handler working, I would be in a huge debt!

Right now I have the following three files:

ds_regions.module

```
function ds_regions_views_api(){
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module','ds_regions')
  );
}
```

ds_regions.views.inc

```
<?php 
function ds_regions_views_handlers() {
  return array(
    'info' => array(
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module','ds_regions'),
  ),
  'handlers' => array(
    'ds_regions_handler_filter_view' => array (
      'parent' => 'views_handler_filter',
      ),
    ),
  );
}

function ds_regions_views_data(){
  $data=array();
  $data['node']['ds_regions_filter']=array(
    'title' => t('ds regions view filter'),
    'help' => t('Filters the nodes by region'),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'ds_regions_handler_filter_view',
    ),
  );
  $data['field_data_field_verein']['table']['join']['node']=array(
    'left_field' => 'nid',
    'field' => 'field_verein_tid',
  );
  $data['ds_vereine']['table']['join']['node']=array(
    'left_field' => 'field_verein_tid',
    'left_table' => 'field_data_field_verein',
    'field' => 'tid',
  );
  return $data;
}
?>
```

ds_regions_handler_filter_view.inc

```
<?php
class ds_regions_handler_filter_view extends views_handler_filter{
  function admin_summary(){}
  function option_definition(){
    $options = parent::option_definition();
    $options['misc'] = array('default' => '1');
    return $options;
  }
  function value_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['custom_filter']  = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield'
    );
  }
  function options_form(){}
  function operator_form(){}
  function query(){
  $table = $this->ensure_my_table();
  $this->query->ensure_table('ds_vereine',$this->relationship);
  $this->query->add_where($this->options['group'],"ds_vereine.plz IN (SELECT ds_plz_distance.plz_first FROM `ds_plz_distance` WHERE ds_plz_distance.distance < 20 AND ds_plz_distance.plz_first=ds_vereine.plz) OR ds_vereine.plz IN (SELECT ds_plz_distance.plz_second FROM `ds_plz_distance` WHERE ds_plz_distance.distance < 20 AND ds_plz_distance.plz_second=ds_vereine.plz) OR ds_vereine.plz IN (SELECT ds_plz_ort.plz FROM `ds_plz_ort` ort WHERE ds_plz_ort.kreis=306)");
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at Drupal 6 documentation.

You don't need `hook_views_handlers()` anymore in D7. Instead, you add the file(s) that contains your views handler(s) to your .info file like this:

```
files[]=ds_regions_handler_filter_view.inc
```

Comment: that actually resolves my issue! one more thing, if I may, my where clause seems to be incorrect, but I do not seem to find the cure. http://www.examiner.com/open-source-in-national/drupal-how-to-create-views-2-filters-for-your-new-module does the same, I guess, but it's not working for me? Thanks anyway!